# Reference second table in Entity with Include

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity

I have 3 tables in my DB

Table 1 has a column that references to Table 2, Table 2 has a column that references to Table 3

Now in entity i want to return a object so I call the value from table 3 when i do the following expression:

```
string table3name = table1.table2.table3.Name;
```

But when I Include table 3 over table 2 i get an error:

```
Table1.Include("Table2").Include("Table3").FirstOrDefault();
```

results in:

```
  A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'BrandweeronlineModel.lt_person_function' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'function_type'.
```

This is true, Because the function_type is referenced in the function table which is referenced by lt_person_function. So lt_person_function is table1  and function_type is table3. But table 2 is between there.

But when I do it as follow:

```
foreach (var tb1 in table1)
      tb1.table2.table3= tb1.table2.table3;
```

it will work correctly but I want to make it work with Includes. How can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Use `Table1.Include("Table2").Include("Table2.Table3")`

Comment: Nice, that worked like a charm! Thank you so much